# create a text layer psd

Tags: python, photoshop

I want to write a function that can create a text layer .

I checked previous questions,most of them uses linux command line operations but the scipt will run on windows 10. I found this module [psd-tools](https://psd-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but after reading the documentation I couldn't find a way to create a text layer (then save .psd).

Ideally I want a function to create the layer like `foo('this is some text')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client
import os

OUTPUT_TEXT = "Hello, World!" #text  \r for new line
OUTPUT_FILENAME = 'foo.psd' #filename
psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application") #dispatching photoshop

originalRulerUnits = psApp.Preferences.RulerUnits
psApp.Preferences.RulerUnits = 1 # 1= psPixesl, 2 = inches

docs = psApp.Documents
docRef = docs.Add(250,33)

layers = docRef.artLayers # all layers
artLayerRef = layers.add

artLayerRef.kind = 2 #Text layer
textItemRef = artLayerRef.TextItem
textItemRef.Contents = OUTPUT_TEXT

psApp.Preferences.RulerUnits = originalRulerUnits 
docs.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME)
#os.startfile(OUTPUT_FILENAME) run your psd to open photoshop
```